# What does the second argument of the read command mean?

Tags: python, syntax, io

I have this Python code:

```
for name, age in read(file, ('name','age')):
```

Could anybody please explain what it means?

Comment: There's no builtin function `read`. Which module is it from? And why don't you read that module's documentation?

Comment: Very poorly asked question, as there is no given context, so does not tell anything about the role of this line of code. *Always* quote your code in wide context, so other people can understand what happens. Ale at least `import` lines would be somehow helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`('name','age')` is a tuple, an [immutable sequence type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange), similar to a list.

If you're asking what it means in regards to the `read()` function, I'm sure that can be found at the specific module's documentation, because `read` is not a built-in function [last I heard](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) :p.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably meant `filename.read(file, ('name','age')):` but the built-in read function has only one parameter and that's size `file.read( size )` it defines the number of bytes to be read from the file so practically this statement `filename.read(file, ('name','age')):` would return an error

But if you have imported some sort of read() function from an *unknown module*, read it's documentation

Answer (score 0):

for name, age in read(file, ('name','age')):

---

for is for for loop

name , age are two variable to retrieve from loop with respect to read function

read is a function who take file as an self variable and name and age is variable